# Why can't I mock Math using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, math, jmockit

I am running into a problem mocking out `java.lang.Math` using JMockit (1.21). See below for a simplified use of my actual class. Basically somewhere in my code I use `Math.pow(...)` and I whish to mock it.

```
public final class Calculator {
    public final double power(double base, double exponent) {
        return Math.pow(base, exponent);
    }
}
```

As for my test code, this test works.

```
@Test
public void simpleTestWithoutMock() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double result = calculator.power(2, 3);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(8);
}
```

This test fails.

```
@Test
public void simpleTestWithMock(@Mocked Math math) {
    new Expectations() {{ // This would be line 67 in below stracktrace
        Math.pow(2,3); result = 1;
    }};

    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double result = calculator.power(2, 3);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

The error message I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl/endran/sandbox/CalculatorTest$1

        at nl.endran.sandbox.CalculatorTest.simpleTestWithMock(CalculatorTest.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.endran.sandbox.CalculatorTest$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 9 more
```

I am able to mock other system classes like `System` and `RunTime` like this, but `Math` just doesn't seem to work (nor does `String` for that matter). I know how to circumvent this is my tests, so I am not blocked or anything, but I cannot understand why `Math` cannot be mocked. Removing the Expectations block will not cause the `NoClassDefFoundError` error anymore. I suspect methods that have a signature like `public static native` to play a role in this, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: consider this: don't mock Math.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408253/how-to-mock-a-static-method-from-jmockit

Comment: @DwB, Yeah, i know that will work, but that doesn't answer my question. What's so special about `Math` that makes it unmockable?

Comment: @Ammar, I am not asking how to mock a static method, I am asking why can't I mock Math?

Comment: Consider asking the question you want answered.  Instead of "How many blueberries fit in a petunia?" ask "How can I fit blueberries in a petunia?" if what you want to know is "How can I fit blueberries in a petunia?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 1) methods from `java.lang.Math` (in particular, `Math.min(a, b)`) get called *all the time* by other classes from the JRE (for example, look inside `java.lang.String`), and 2) when JMockit mocks a class (with `@Mocked`, anyway), it gets mocked for the duration of the test, regardless of *where* the calls are coming from.

Bottom line, don't mock low-level JRE classes unless you really know what you are doing. In this particular case, JMockit should probably deny the full mocking of `java.lang.Math`, as really there is no good reason (that I can see) for doing it.

Comment: I can agree for not having a proper reason to mock Math, apart from Math.random().. Also I can see the dependencies of the entire system on these low level classes. However, I think that both point 1 and 2 might be a sufficient reason as to why not to mock lower level classes, still I would like to see some formal proof.

Comment: How about in order to use Verifications to make sure `pow()` was called? I agree mocking `Math` is a bad idea, but verifying seems to be a good idea... In order to avoid discussion in the comments, I've created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727719/how-to-use-verifications-on-an-un-mockable-type-in-jmockit) to address this issue.