# Why can't I get JMockit coverage report with static method?

Tags: java, testng, jmockit, test-coverage

I need to get a report from my unit test. I found and used JMockit plugin to mock different environments which were required for tests. But I found that I can't get the coverage report when I mock static methods. The mock tests all ran successfully. See the report screenshot below:

[image: Coverage Result]
[image: Coverage Code Line]

So is there any problem in my code? Maybe somebody who has better experience with JMockit can you help me with this. Thanks.

You can get the code from here:

1. [Maven Pom File](https://github.com/elkan1788/mpsdk4j/blob/develop/pom.xml)
2. [Static Source Code](https://github.com/elkan1788/mpsdk4j/blob/develop/src/main/java/io/github/elkan1788/mpsdk4j/util/HttpTool.java)
3. [Test Code](https://github.com/elkan1788/mpsdk4j/blob/develop/src/test/java/io/github/elkan1788/mpsdk4j/util/HttpToolTest.java)

Comment: Another reason to avoid using static methods -- they make your code difficult to test.

Comment: Maybe this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408253/how-to-mock-a-static-method-from-jmockit

Comment: Looking at the tests in `HttpToolTest`, they all seem rather pointless to me, as each test simply checks that JMockit itself is working...

Comment: Or, to put @Rogério's comment another way ... if you are testing a method, ***do not mock that method***. When a method is mocked, flow of control never enters that method and you won't actually test (or get coverage for) that method. You should be mocking the objects that `HttpTool` uses, not `HttpTool` itself.

Comment: @dcsohl Thanks for you reply. Actually I also had a class reference the HttpTool, but the coverage not show up in report.

Comment: Perhaps you would be so bold as to include that information in your question? Better yet, a [small complete project that replicates your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so somebody else can take a look?

Comment: @dcsohl yeah, Now I had build a simple project, can you take a look? thanks. --> https://github.com/elkan1788/jmockit-study